# Rails before_filter check for protected page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie to rails.  I want to check if a page is protected and if it's protected then redirect the user to a login page. It's not working for some reason.

I added this to the top of the controller:

```
before_filter :check_access, :only => [:show]
```

I added this code to the Posts controller:

```
def check_access
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to login_url unless @post.published != '2'
end
```

Comment: why woudn't you just do if @post.published = '2'? unless with a ! is not good ruby

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful to describe the symptoms. Instead of "it's not working for some reason" - try "The protected page is loading instead of redirecting".

Comment: are you sure that `published` method returns a string? If it returns a Fixnum this condition will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful to diagnose the issue.  I'm assuming @post.published is a flag indicating the post is published.  You could make sure the *login_url* path is setup correctly from the console.

```
rake routes | grep "login_url"
```

Comment: i SOLVED IT, SORRY DIDN'T REALIZE anyone responded